# VueJS method does not execute after I reload page, it executes after I save VS Code change [HELP?]

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex

After I reload the page I can't get console.log inside of the method, which means it is not getting executed, but after I make change in VSC and save it, the method executes.

I would like to add note that I have show/hide modal for the form where I try to pre-fill the values, does that makes problem? I tried removing the toggle and the result was the same.

Pls see screenshots

[image: 1]

Some code below:

```
 created() {
    this.loadStationList();
    this.loadStationGroups();
    this.loadAllButtons();
    this.loadAllQuidos();
    this.pushButtonIds(); <---- I Try to execute this method on created but it gets executed after VS code change
  },
```

```
  pushButtonIds() {
      for (const buttonId in this.filteredButtonList) {
        this.stationButtons.push({
          buttonId: this.filteredButtonList[buttonId].buttonListId,
          quidoId: null,
          input: null,
        });
        console.log(this.stationButtons);
        console.log("Hello from component after saving change in VSC");
      }
    },
```

I tried to add the method to execute on beforeCreated but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the name, without knowing exactly, where `filteredButtonList` comes from, it looks to me that you call this function too early. Accessing DOM elements should take place when everything is actually in the DOM. Try moving the call into `beforeMount()` or even `mounted()`. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html